# GPIO pins not working properly

Tags: gpio, python-3

i've recently started a small project where i want to controle an LED-strip with an webapp using a respberry pi. While the webapp works perfectly fine, i ran into a problem with my pi zero w. Since the pi cant deliver the power the LED-strip needs, ive repurposed the strips controlerboard by soddering some cables to the transistors (Every transistor controles a color). Ive already tested this contraption by plugging the wires into the 3.3V pin. This works perfectly fine. Ive now tried to plug them into the gpio pins and started an shh session. In there i opened the console typed in python3 and ran the following lines:

```
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
gpio.setmode(gpio.BCM)
gpio.setup(2, gpio.OUT)
gpio.setup(3, gpio.OUT)
gpio.setup(4, gpio.OUT)
gpio.output(2, gpio.HIGH)
gpio.output(3, gpio.HIGH)
gpio.output(4, gpio.HIGH)
```

The Problem here is that only one pin (in this case it was pin 4) works properly. When changing the cables up, only the LEDs connected to pin 4 turned on. I checked if ive got the right pin and even turned every pin to HIGH but nothing changed. The next thing i tried was using different pins, but the result was the same. No matter how i pluged them in or what pin combination i chose, only one pin(sometimes even none) would work. If one pin worked the last time and i tried to use it again, it didnt work this time.

Another thing i noticed was that everytime i unplugged a cable while the pin was still setup in the terminal, the pi would restart. My gues would be that somehow the voltage droped, but i have no idea why.

If anyone knows what im doing wrong, id appreciate the help.

-Timo

P.S:
The following is my setup with pin 2, 3, 4.

Edit:
As per comment recommended, Ive now run the gpiotest of the pigpio library. How ever the results disturbed me even more. The test came back with the result "Failed user gpios: 25". Since i already had connected the cables to pins 23, 24 and 25, I decided to test them manually and put these pins to HIGH. Well the only pin that turned the LEDs on was pin 25.
I have no idea whats going on here.

[image]

Comment: have you tried other pins?

Comment: Test the GPIO with https://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Testing

Comment: pins 2 & 3 may be used for i2c if you configured it in config.txt - perhaps that's the issue?

Comment: I've also tried pins 14, 15, 18, 23, 24, 25 (BCM). In all cases the result was the same